# Showing all output in the console VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, settings, console.log

I am using `console.log` in my javascript program in VS code to output to the console a lot of values. When I print a few values to the console using `console.log`, I am able to see every value in the console window as normal. But when there are a lot of them, the values seem to get cut off. Is there some sort of option in VS code that allows me to print everything to the console without it being cut off at some limit?

Answer (score 31):

Go to File>Preferences>Setting and search for the Scrollback setting and increase the value to get the number of lines of output you want.

This worked for me.

Comment: Just one FYI - There is another option of `persistent session scrollback` in vscode just above the normal `scrollback` option. It is used to display the number of lines when vscodes restores a terminal session(like when you close or accidentally close the vscode). You might NOT want to set it though, as it will take up memory and slow down the terminal. So set only `scrollback` option only unless you need `persistent scrollback` also.

Answer (score 6):

For MAC users:

Code => Preferences => Settings => (Search for "scrollback") => Write higher number for "Terminal › Integrated: Scrollback".

Answer (score 2):

inside vs code settings search for scrollback option and change the second option to number of lines you want [vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V592b.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you need to make a change in your launch.json configuration of xdebug in VS Code.

The piece of configuration you will need to add to your configuration of launch.json is "xdebugSettings": { "max_data": -1 }

A simple configuration should look like that

`{ "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [ { "name": "Listen for XDebug", "type": "php", "request": "launch", "port": 9000, "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/myapp/", "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/", "xdebugSettings": { "max_data": -1 } }] }`

xdebugSettings.max_data Controls the maximum string length that is shown when variables are displayed. To disable any limitation, use -1 as value.

Good luck.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, PHP XDebug max buffer limit just didn't think I would find it in a JS debug question, haha, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the string is large then use log("value".tosting()). to check the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).