# Can not get the full response form the post request in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, httprequest, cross-platform

I have a post request in Flutter to get the data in the body, but the debug console in vs code only displayed a part of the response.
But when I go to the console in the Flutter devtool, I can see all the responses.

Can anybody provide the solution to get all the responses to the request, please?

Comment: can you share a code snippet responsible for the issue?

Comment: Apologies, I'm unable to share the code snippet. However, I believe there's likely a maximum permitted length limitation for responses in the request.

Comment: try to create a sample snippet

Comment: the debug console in vscode is limiting to display , try to increase your limit (it's vscode thing not your response) check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013673/showing-all-output-in-the-console-vs-code

Comment: Thank you, i have found the answer for the question, I use log() method in "dart: develop" package instead, so I can log all the response with no limit